# DB2 "with ur" in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am migrating quite a few data processing jobs from DB2 to Hive.

I came across a "select" query in DB2 ending with the clause "with ur" like the below one:

```
select field1, field2 from table1 where field3=value1 with ur
```

The "with ur" clause is known to be used for *uncommitted read*.

I am not using "transactions" in Hive.

Interestingly I came across the below Hive java-docs link that mentions "with ur" option as part of "select".
https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r2.0.1/api/org/apache/hive/hplsql/Select.html#option(org.apache.hive.hplsql.HplsqlParser.Select_options_itemContext)

However, the language manual in the below link does not mention such an option:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select

Can someone please advise how i should deal this situation in Hive?

Comment: Your "interesting" URL is not related to Hive. It points to the new, optional, Hive **HPL/SQL plug-in** which is _"...an open source tool (Apache License 2.0) that implements procedural SQL language for Apache Hive, SparkSQL, Impala as well as any other SQL-on-Hadoop implementation, any NoSQL and **any RDBMS**"_  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59690156

Comment: So you can plug HPL/SQL into DB2, using DB2-specific options. You can also plug it into Teradata, using Teradata-specific options. Etc.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I use CDH5.8 which does not include HPQ/SQL. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: Why do you bother about DB2 options with a weird syntax??? Hive does not support transactions by default, so you don't give a sheet about transaction isolation. Full stop.